# JPA em.remove doesn't return error and doesn't remove anything (silently fails)

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I have a remove method in an EJB as below

```
@Override
public void remove(Project project)
{
    em.remove(em.merge(project));
}
```

The project I pass has been retrieved from another class as shown below:

```
try
 {
        Project tmpProject = getProjectEJB().getById(projectId);
        getProjectEJB().remove(tmpProject);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {..}
```

the result of the remove is that is doesn't remove the object (which is quite reasonable in itself because Project has several relationships pointing to it) what I can't understand is why JPA doesn't return any error but simply silently fails.

Comment: do you have any logs ?

Comment: I am debugging this under Netbeans and all logs are shown, this particular method however doesn't return any error, it simply correctly executes. If I put a catch for an Exception no exception is returned.

Comment: Is the EntityManager joined to a transaction?  SQL is only issued on commit or flush

Comment: show_sql to true ?, you can see any query related to the operation of delete the entity ?

Comment: @Chris **Is the EntityManager joined to a transaction?** how do I find that out? the entity manager is working fine for many other classes..

Comment: Try calling em.flush(), and post how you are creating transactions.  This should show in the logs as well.